# How to change the skeleton color in the KinectSkeletonViewer provided by the SDK v1.6

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I want to change the KinectSkeletonViewer control provided in the Kinect examples.
I want to expose a property to change the color of the skeleton (tracked bones).

What i need to do?

Comment: You want a bindable property in the viewer?  i.e. `<kt:SkeletonViewer BoneColor="Red">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to modify two files - `KinectSkeleton.cs` and `KinectSkeletonViewer.xaml.cs`.  You're creating the binding on the `KinectSkeleton` but, because this class is not directly referenced and called from the viewer, you also need to create a passthrough binding in `KinectSkeletonViewer`.

**KinectSkeleton.cs** - create the DependencyProperties:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TrackedJointBrushProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TrackedJointBursh",
        typeof(Brush),
        typeof(KinectSkeleton),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 68, 192, 68)), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

public static readonly DependencyProperty TrackedBonePenProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TrackedBonePen",
        typeof(Pen),
        typeof(KinectSkeleton),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Pen(Brushes.Green, TrackedBoneThickness), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
```

**KinectSkeletonViewer** - create the DependencyProperties

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TrackedJointBrushProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TrackedJointBursh",
        typeof(Brush),
        typeof(KinectSkeletonViewer),
        new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 68, 192, 68))));

public static readonly DependencyProperty TrackedBonePenProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TrackedBonePen",
        typeof(Pen),
        typeof(KinectSkeletonViewer),
        new PropertyMetadata(new Pen(Brushes.Green, TrackedBoneThickness)));
```

In **both files** define the associated properties:

```
public Brush TrackedJointBursh
{
    get { return (Brush)GetValue(TrackedJointBrushProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TrackedJointBrushProperty, value); }
}

public Pen TrackedBonePen
{
    get { return (Pen)GetValue(TrackedBonePenProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TrackedBonePenProperty, value); }
}
```

Now you want to link the binding.  In the `OnLoad` event of **KinectSkeletonViewer** -

```
var trackedJointBrush = new Binding("TrackedJointBrush");
trackedJointBrush.Source = this;
skeletonCanvas.SetBinding(KinectSkeleton.TrackedJointBrushProperty, trackedJointBrush);

var trackedBonePen = new Binding("TrackedBonePen");
trackedBonePen.Source = this;
skeletonCanvas.SetBinding(KinectSkeleton.TrackedBonePenProperty, trackedBonePen);
```

Finally, you need to look through **KinectSkeleton.cs** and replace reference of the hard coded colors with the new properties.  `trackedJointBrush` and `trackedBonePen` in the case of the above examples - replaced with `TrackedJointBrush` and `TrackedBonePen` (note case).  You can then comment out the hard coded variables.

You should now be able to bind those two properties in the `KinectSkeletonViewer` when you declare it in XAML.

There are a few other colors defined in the `KinectSkeleton` class.  You can use the same concept as above to bind them as well.

Comment: Thanks, I had already done this, but for some reason the property was not being shown in xaml